# How to handle huge amount of changes in real time planning?

Tags: optaplanner

If real time planning and daemon mode is enabled, when an update or addition of planning entity is to be made a problem fact change must be invoked.

So let say the average rate of change will be 1/sec, so for every second a problem fact change must be called resulting to restarting the solver every second.

Do we just invoke or schedule a problem fact change every second resulting to restarting the solver every second or if we know that there will be huge amount of changes, stop the solver first, apply changes then start the solver?

Comment: SO is only for questions related to programming or use of a programmer's tool. You're looking for [su] instead. You can find more information about this site in the [help].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scenario you describe, the solver will be likely restarted every time. It's not a complete restart as if you just call the `Solver.solve()` with the updated last known solution, but the `ScoreDirector`, a component responsible for score calculation, is restarted each time a problem change is applied.

If problem changes come faster, they might be processed in a batch. The solver checks problem changes between the evaluation of individual moves, so if multiple changes come before the solver finishes the evaluation of the current move, they are all applied and the solver restarts just once. In the opposite case, when there are seldom changes coming, the restart doesn't matter much, as there is enough time for the solver to improve the solution.

But the rate of 1 change/sec will likely lead to frequent solver restarts and will affect its ability to produce better solutions.

The solver does not know if there is going to be a bigger amount of changes in the next second. The current behavior may be improved by processing the problem changes periodically in a predefined time interval rather than between move evaluations.

Of course, the periodic grouping of problem changes can be done outside the solver as well.